# Javascript: How to check if an array item is greater than twice an item in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
let arr2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
```

What I want to do is check if any item in `arr2` is greater than or equal to twice any item in arr1. For example, `6` in `arr2` is greater than 2*2 in arr1.

My first solution is

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
    if (i >= j * 2) {
      return true
    }
  }
}
```

Expected result: return true if any item in `arr2` is greater than or equal to twice any item in arr1.

But I am in search of a linear solution to this problem.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: roughly the same as previous post 1h ago

Comment: Not at all @Pierre.

Comment: I made an edit @NinaScholz.

Comment: btw, you are comparing indices, not values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a miminum value of `array1`, get the double and check against the minimum of `array2`.

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    array2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    result = Math.min(...array2) > 2 * Math.min(...array1);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first find the absolute minimum at first array and then compare it to the second array.

Reducing it to O(arr1.length + arr2.length)

If twice the minimum is greater than any element in arr2 then none is lower.

This code seems wrong:

```
if (i >= j * 2)
{
      return true
}
```

should be

```
if (arr2[i] >= arr1[j] * 2)
{
      return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want boolean value result, you can use `some` with combination of `find`.

```js
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
let arr2 = [6,7,8,9,10]

const num = arr2.some(num => arr1.find(x => num >= (x * 2)))

console.log(num);
```